# JSDOC Comment format

Tags: javascript, polymer, documentation, jsdoc

I have a property in a polymer class inside static property getter, defined like this, with comment about it above the property.

```
  /**
  * when textElement is empty, textElement (<text> tag) is used for limited text instead of advanced text features.
  * @name textElement
  * @alias textElement
  * @memberof ABC
  * @type {Boolean}
  */
  textElement: {
    type: String,
    value: ''
  },
```

I am generating documentation for the same using JSDOC, and I am encountering a weird problem, In the generated docs, this is how how comment mentioned over property looks like.

```
when textElement is empty, textElement ( tag) is used for limited text instead of advanced text features.
```

Somehow, while generating documentation JSDOC in the not understanding `<text>` in the comment.

Any insights on this will be helpful, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem, As we know that.

- `&lt;` stands for the [less-than sign][1] ( < ).
- `&gt;` stands for the [greater-than sign][2] ( > ).

Replace `<` with `&lt;` and > with `&gt;` in the comment will solve the problem.